# Post Object or array of Objects to API

Tags: python, arrays, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I would like to have a REST API endpoint where I can post a json object or a json array of objects.

I managed to do so by redefining the create method of my ModelViewSet:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.DATA, many=False)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
        else:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.DATA, many=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I used is_valid() from the serializer to know if the data contains an object or an array (many is set to True or False), but because of that I lose the serializer validation for other purposes like field validations.

Is there a better way to achieve that behaviour?

Should I instead create another function with another url to be able to post an array of objects? What is the REST way to support both operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django REST Framework does not support bulk object creation by default, but there are packages out there that add support for it, such as [Django REST Framework Bulk](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk).

It can be made to [work with routers](https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk/issues/11) with slight modifications. This should allow you to do what you are looking for.

> because of that I lose the serializer validation for other purposes like field validations.

This is because you were not passing in the serializer context, which generic views do automatically.

Comment: Just had an issue with it (https://github.com/miki725/django-rest-framework-bulk/issues/22), but this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!